# Uiautomator - cannot use UiObject2

Tags: android-uiautomator

I'm trying to create a new UiObject2 in UiAutomator but I receive the following message:

`UiObject2(android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice, android.support.test.uiautomator.BySelector, android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo)` is not public in 'android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject2'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
UiObject2 resultsObj = mDevice.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.ExpandableListView").res("android:id/list").pkg(PACKAGE_NAME).scrollable(true));
```

Did you add `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'` in `projectRoot-app module-build.gralde`?
And write your test code under `app module-androidTest`?

Comment: And claim your device as `UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());`.

Comment: I see, you may have tried `UiObject2 demoObj = new UiObject2();`  
Actually it works when `UiObject2 demoObj = UiDevice.findObject(By(xxx))`.

Comment: public UiObject2 findObject(BySelector selector) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo node = ByMatcher.findMatch(this, selector, getWindowRoots());
        return node != null ? new UiObject2(this, selector, node) : null;
    }